# When I open a custom UIView from a UITableViewController, how do I close the custom view and go back to the table view?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableViewController` for a menu in a game. The table view opens a a view controller for my custom `UIView` that shows the game. When the game finishes the `UIView` is notified (which is kinda ruining the MVC principals) and from there I am kinda lost.

Questions:

1. Can a `UIView` communicate with its controller? How?
2. Can one controller talk to the one that started it? How?
3. How do I transition between all of this complicated web of views and controllers gracefully?

Comment: What I did in the end:
Create a "game controller" with the all the game specific actions. Create a view controller that inherits from the game controller.
After initialization set the view's parent to the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a delegate protocol here.  Your custom game UIView can use a `delegate` property and call methods on this delegate when events happen (game over, game paused, view closed, etc).  Here's a great post on using delegates: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)
2. I'd recommend using a UINavigationController.  You don't necessarily need to show the navigation bar, but if you nest your view controllers in a navigation controller you have access to `-pushViewControllerAnimated:` and `-popViewControllerAnimated:` which make it really easy to navigation between levels of nested view controllers.
3. Another benefit of UINavigationController - you'll get a nice slide animation when you switch between views.

There are other 3rd party mechanisms out there that you may prefer over the UIKit UINavigationController/UIViewController mechanisms.  Check out the [Three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master), in particular the TTNavigationCenter class.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I need something a bit deeper than that to actually understand why UIView doesn't have a parent / controller field, and how to do this **right**, not pretty.

Comment: I think the delegate idea is the right one for the first question, and it's the most common way of passing messages out of a UIView without breaking MVC too badly. The thought of a navigation controller is also good - a navigation controller is basically a stack of view controllers, so each controller has a sense of its "parent" controller. This answer seems to fit pretty well, both in the sense of doing things "right" and doing things "pretty." +1

Comment: Furthermore, a UIView doesn't have a parent/controller field because a UIView doesn't necessarily have to have a controller. It may have a superview, which is a property of the view object.

Comment: UIViewController does have a parentViewController property, but that's only useful with UINavigationController or similar UIKit controllers.  Note, I added a link to the Three20 project - you may find TTNavigationCenter solves some of your problems.

Comment: Tim's second comment was the answer I was looking for. Thanks :)